# Sony Camera API change exposure parameters?

Tags: camera, sony

Looking at the supported API's for various camera both within the PDF docs and the supported cameras page (https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/), it looks like the A7R supports changing f stop, shutter speed, ISO, etc. However, within the iOS sample app none of those commands are provided by the camera as being available via the getAvailableApiList command. "Forcing" a setIsoSpeedRate command to the camera didn't work either and I get an error code 403: Forbidden.

So is this supported? Am I missing something? Does the camera need to be configured in a particular way? Of note, I am running firmware 1.10 on the A7R, which I believe is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest version (ver.3.10) of “Smart Remote Control” application of PlayMemories Camera App and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only had a 4 week period with the camera and had to send it back. However, I'm pretty sure that the PlayMemories Camera App was not installed when I received the camera and so installed it in early December. So it should have had version 3.10, which came out in October. It is possible I'm remembering incorrectly, though did v 3.10 explicitly add support for these features? The info for v 3.10 doesn't seem to mention anything relevant.